# Show Bootstrap 4 modal but keep a href working inside the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an add to cart button on my Bootstrap 4 based ecommerce website. I want to add a modal trigger to the Add to Cart button (to display an instruction) and everything is OK but if I try to add the modal trigger directly inside the button:

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="buynow" href="/?add-to-cart=51" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Purchase</a>
```

The `#modal-1` displays, but the product is not added to the cart (href functional doesn't work)

And when I try to display the modal without adding the `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1"` attributes with the following way:

```
$('#buynow').click(function(){
  $('#modal-1').modal('show')
});
```

The modal window appears for a couple of seconds, but then the link follows to the Cart page due to `href=/?add-to-cart=51` redirection.

What is the right thing to do if I want the product to be added to the cart (thanks to a href trigger), but the modal window still appears and there is no redirection when the modal shows?

Comment: add `return false` to your click event (or use https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) then make an ajax post based on your href

Comment: thank you! sorry, where exactly I have to add this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden link

```
<div class="add-to-cart-btn">
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-warning"  id="buynow"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Purchase</a>

    <a role="button" class="d-none add-to-cart"  href="/?add-to-cart=51" ></a>
    </div>
    $('#buynow').click(function(){
      $('#modal-1').modal('show')
      $(this).closest('.add-to-cart-btn').find('.add-to-cart').trigger("click");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it didn't help :(

Comment: I mean the modal displays, but the product is not added :(

Comment: I think is because you have multiple add To Cart buttons with same ID try to change id by add index

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use data attribute like

```
   <a role="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="add-to-cart" data-url="/?add-to-cart=51" href="#modal-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Purchase</a>
```

and your modal should look like this

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-1"
    aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...whatever here. maybe a loading image?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and than call the URL

```
    $('#modal-1').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-body').load(button.data("url"));
    });
```

Note I am just loading the content in modal from `load(button.data("url")` , you can manipulate data attribute any way you wants, for example maybe you can just assign a data attribute with id of product `data-id="51"` and than in `'show.bs.modal'` event you can call an Ajax request to perform certain action with it.